# Posso configurar para o GitLab-CI só executar determinado job com um pattern de nome de branch?

Tags: integração-contínua, gitlab

Estou usando o GitLab para gerenciamento de evolução de código. Tudo tranquilo em relação a isso. Uso *merge-requests* para revisar alterações de código. Também uso de modo geral o [GitFlow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), só que usando o nome `rc-*` para branches de lançamento (o GitFlow prevê `release-*`).

Resumidamente sobre o GitFlow, ele tem nomenclatura para os branhces, casa um tem um objetivo:

- `master`
  é o branch com o código de produção, portanto código relativamente estável
- `develop`
  é o branch com o código de desenvolvimento, portanto código relativamente instável
- `rc-*`
  é o branch com o candidato de lançamento (*release candidate*), é derivado do `develop` e (quando maduro o suficiente) será integrado no `master`

  ex: `rc-1.2` é o candidato de lançamento para a versão `1.2`

No GitLab, eu posso configurar um *build* usando o [GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html). Essa configuração é feita no arquivo `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Nesse arquivo de configuração, posso determinar *jobs* que são executados condicionalmente ([documentação](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified)).

Por exemplo, eu posso querer que o GitLab só execute o *job* `deploy-lib` nos branches `master` e `develop`:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn compile

deploy-lib:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn deploy
  only:
    - master
    - develop
```

Eu gostaria de adicionar um *job* para só ser executado em branches que sigam o *pattern* `rc-*`. Não encontrei nada na documentação a respeito de *pattern name* para o `jobs:only`, mas isso é usado em diversos cantos no GitLab web.

Então, pergunto:

- Posso configurar para o GitLab-CI só executar determinado *job* para branches que satisfação o *pattern*  `rc-*`? Se sim, como faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação, sim, é possível.

> Leia a [documentação detalhada](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/yaml/README#only-and-except-simplified)

Além das palavras-chaves (como `branches` e `tags`), você pode especificar o nome do *branch* verbatim. Na questão, o `job:deploy-libs` vai ser executado quando chamado no *branch* `master` ou no `develop`.

Para usar exepressões regulares, coloque a expressão **/entre barras/**. Então, como é desejado adicionar o padrão `rc-*`, em regex o equivalente seria (já pondo as barras requeridas) `/^rc-.*$/`

Neste caso, o `.gitlab-ci.yml` ficaria assim:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn compile

deploy-lib:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn deploy
  only:
    - master
    - develop
    - /^rc-.*$/
```